# TYPO3 EXT:form custom finisher: Error handling

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I've written a custom finisher for EXT:form. In this finisher, I submit a request to a REST API. When this request fails, I want to show the last step of the form again with an error or flash message.
Is this somehow possible or is it just possible to throw an exception (FinisherException) in the finisher?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FlashMessageFinisher`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Finishers/FlashMessageFinisher.php) in your custom finisher and call it like follows:

```php
$flashMessageFinisher = $this->objectManager->get(FlashMessageFinisher::class);
$flashMessageFinisher->setOptions([
  'messageBody' => $errorMessage, 
  'messageCode' => $errorCode, 
  'severity' => AbstractMessage::ERROR,
]);
$flashMessageFinisher->execute($this->finisherContext);
$this->finisherContext->cancel();
```

Comment: Thx, I already use FlashMessages in my custom Finisher.
But how to display the last step of the form again (and giving the user the possibility to submit the form again, without having to begin from the start).

Comment: This question's old, but was never finally answered. So in case anybody else finds this question: In order to handle this kind of scenario, you need to use a validator instead of a finisher. See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Validators/Index.html -> custom validators