# How to throw an error or a message in form finisher after executing an API call in TYPO3 11.5.28?

Tags: typo3

I implemented a form finisher in TYPO3 11 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546931/why-does-my-custom-form-finisher-not-exist-in-typo3-11-5-28-composer/). It sends data to an API and gets as feedback an errorcode.

The API-call is done in the following function (and works like a charm):

```
protected function executeInternal()
{
   ...
}
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371129/typo3-extform-custom-finisher-error-handling) I could use a flash messages to throw an error in the frontend.
After integrating it in the function like this:

```
protected function executeInternal()
{
    $flashMessageFinisher = $this->objectManager->get(FlashMessageFinisher::class);
    $flashMessageFinisher->setOptions([
       'messageBody' => 'Test', 
       'messageCode' => 'Testmessage', 
       'severity' => AbstractMessage::ERROR,
    ]);
    $flashMessageFinisher->execute($this->finisherContext);
    $this->finisherContext->cancel();
}
```

The message classes are also included:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Error;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Message;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Notice;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Warning;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageRendererResolver;
```

Unfortunately I get the following error in the frontend:

```
Call to a member function get() on null
```

Is there someone who knows how to throw a message from this function? Or is it not possible? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a condition in your controller to show the message. Something like this:

```
if($this->request->hasArgument('form'))
{
 $form = $this->request->getArgument('form');
 $cancellation_info = $this->cancellationProcess($form);

 if($cancellation_info['cancellation'] == 'successful') {
   $this->addFlashMessage(
    'BLA BLA BLA'
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the system throws an error after submitting the form: "Call to a member function hasArgument() on null". Maybe I need another function, isn't it?